# How to use shell script within a python program?

Tags: python, csh, os.system

I want to use a C-shell script within a python program, which works with two arguments.

```
os.system("recall 20170121 ../E725.txt xy 1")
```

But I want to use it for a stack, so declared the variables like below, but when I call them within the script it gives an error, that the input file doesn't exist. How can I call the variables?

```
date_ID=(filename[17:25])
fullpath = '../%s' % (filename)
os.system("import_S1_TOPS_modified $date_ID $fullpath vv 1")
```

Answer (score 1):

The shell doesn't know about the Python variables, as it's a completely different system. So you can't use the shell's variable substitution mechanism (`$date_ID`). Instead, you'll have to pass them as a Python string:

```
os.system("import_S1_TOPS_modified %s %s vv 1" % (date_ID, fullpath))
```

---

Note that this code has a serious problem: what if someone gives `; rm -rf /;` as `filename`? the command will now look like:

```
import_S1_TOPS_modified 20181021; rm -rf /; vv 1
```

Which will delete everything.

This is why it is a better idea to use `subprocess`, which will not use the shell at all, and isn't vulnerable to this sort of problem:

```
subprocess.call(['import_S1_TOPS_modified', date_ID, fullpath, 'vv', '1'])
```

If you must use the shell, then use `shlex.quote()` and add `shell=True`:

```
subprocess.call("import_S1_TOPS_modified %s %s vv 1" % (
    shlex.quote(date_ID), shlex.quote(fullpath)),
    shell=True)
```